# Merge sorting a singly-linked list in C - follow-up

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

(See the [initial iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138366/merge-sorting-a-singly-linked-list-in-c).)

Continuing from [Merge sorting a singly-linked list in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138366/merge-sorting-a-singly-linked-list-in-c), I have incorporated the points made by @vnp.

Now it looks like this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list_node {
    int value;
    struct linked_list_node* next;
} linked_list_node;

/*******************************************************************************
* This fuction converts the command line arguments to a linked list.           *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* build_linked_list_from_args(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    linked_list_node* list = calloc(argc - 1, sizeof(*list));

    for (size_t node_index = 0; node_index < argc - 1; ++node_index)
    {
        list[node_index].value = atoi(argv[1 + node_index]);
        list[node_index].next  = node_index == argc - 2 ?
                                    NULL :
                                    &list[node_index + 1];
    }

    return list;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This function prints the entire linked list to stdout.                       *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print(linked_list_node* head)
{
    printf("[");
    linked_list_node* current_node = head;

    if (current_node)
    {
        printf("%d", current_node->value);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    while (current_node)
    {
        printf(" %d", current_node->value);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    printf("]");
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This function merges stabily the two input lists that are expected to be     *
* sorted.                                                                      *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* merge(linked_list_node* left_head,
                               linked_list_node* right_head)
{
    linked_list_node* merged_list_head;
    linked_list_node* merged_list_tail;

    if (right_head->value < left_head->value)
    {
        merged_list_head = right_head;
        merged_list_tail = right_head;
        right_head = right_head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        merged_list_head = left_head;
        merged_list_tail = left_head;
        left_head = left_head->next;
    }

    while (left_head && right_head)
    {
        if (right_head->value < left_head->value)
        {
            merged_list_tail->next = right_head;
            merged_list_tail = right_head;
            right_head = right_head->next;
        }
        else
        {
            merged_list_tail->next = left_head;
            merged_list_tail = left_head;
            left_head = left_head->next;
        }
    }

    merged_list_tail->next = left_head ? left_head : right_head;
    return merged_list_head;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This function splits the input linked list in two sublists and returns the   *
* head of the right one.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* split(linked_list_node* head)
{
    linked_list_node* slow = head;
    linked_list_node* fast = head;
    linked_list_node* prev_slow = NULL;

    while (fast && fast->next)
    {
        prev_slow = slow;
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }

    linked_list_node* right_sublist_head = prev_slow->next;
    prev_slow->next = NULL;
    return right_sublist_head;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This function implements the actual sorting routine.                         *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* sort_impl(linked_list_node* head)
{
    if (!head->next)
    {
        return head;
    }

    linked_list_node* right_sublist_head = split(head);
    return merge(sort_impl(head), sort_impl(right_sublist_head));
}

/*******************************************************************************
* This function sorts the input linked list whose the first node is 'head'.    *
*******************************************************************************/
linked_list_node* sort(linked_list_node* head)
{
    if (!head || !head->next)
    {
        return head;
    }

    return sort_impl(head);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    linked_list_node* head = build_linked_list_from_args(argc, argv);
    print(head);
    puts("");
    head = sort(head);
    print(head);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

As always, any critique is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Utilize `const` to indicate the referenced data is not changed and allow optimizations.

   ```
   // static void print(linked_list_node* head)
   static void print(const linked_list_node* head)
   ```
2. In `print()`, code repeated all for the sake of a `" "`.  Suggested simplification:

   ```
   const char *sep = "";
   while (current_node) {
       printf("%s%d", sep, current_node->value);
       sep = " ";
       current_node = current_node->next;
   }
   ```
3. I'd expect non-`static` function names tailored to linked lists.  Example: `sort()` is too likely to collide with other code.

   ```
   // linked_list_node* sort(linked_list_node* head)
   linked_list_node* linked_list_sort(linked_list_node* head)
   ```
4. Many functions are `static`.  None of these should be in the same .c file as `main()`.  Better to have all linked list functions in a file like `linked_list.c` with a corresponding `linked_list.h` header file.
5. Expect more that just `sort()` to not be static.  Certainly `build_linked_list_from_args()` is meant to be visible.
6. Consider a call like `merge(list1, list1)`.  Will code work?  If that functionality is not needed, use `restrict` to indicate that and allow more optimizations.

   ```
   // linked_list_node* merge(linked_list_node* left_head, linked_list_node* right_head)
   linked_list_node* merge(linked_list_node* restrict left_head, 
       linked_list_node* restrict right_head)
   ```

**Minor**

1. Spelling `fuction` --> `function`.
2. `sizeof(*list)` can be coded simpler as `sizeof *list`.  (style issue)
3. Not a fan of using `printf(string)` to print strings.  `printf()` expects that first argument to point to a string used as a *format* - which is a problem should it contain `"%"`.  Consider `fputs(string, stdout)`
4. Uncertain that `const` is generally OK in `main()`.  Since it is test code, suggest simplifying.

   ```
   // int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
   int main(int argc, char * argv[])
   ```
5. Add date and your ID (name) to the file as a comment.
6. Format: The below format is hard to maintain with automatic formatting tools (at least mine).  Maybe it does well with yours.  Formatting is a pain and should not be maintained manually.  Assuming you did not use such a tool, try one.

   ```
   static linked_list_node* merge(linked_list_node* left_head,
                                  linked_list_node* right_head)
   ```

[Edit]

Simplified `merge()`, only `while()` loop needed.
Down-side: need a `linked_list_node` variable and not just a `linked_list_node *`.

```
static linked_list_node *merge(linked_list_node *left, linked_list_node *right) {
  linked_list_node head;  // Only use next field
  linked_list_node *tail = &head;

  while (left && right) {
    if (right->value < left->value) {
      tail->next = right;
      tail = right;
      right = right->next;
    } else {
      tail->next = left;
      tail = left;
      left = left->next;
    }
  }

  tail->next = left ? left : right;
  return head.next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Readability regarding docstrings**:

You've written docstrings to describe your functions as following: "This function [describes what the function does]".

```
/*******************************************************************************
* This function splits the input linked list in two sublists and returns the   *
* head of the right one.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* split(linked_list_node* head)



/*******************************************************************************
* This function sorts the input linked list whose the first node is 'head'.    *
*******************************************************************************/
linked_list_node* sort(linked_list_node* head)
```

Beginning every docstring with "This function" is redundant and hurts readability. Any potential reader knows that the subject of the comment is a function. Instead:

```
/*******************************************************************************
* Splits the input linked list in two sublists and returns the
* head of the right one.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
static linked_list_node* split(linked_list_node* head)



/*******************************************************************************
* Sorts the input linked list whose the first node is 'head'.
*******************************************************************************/
linked_list_node* sort(linked_list_node* head)
```

It may seem petty but if the reader was scanning between a large number of docstrings, it makes a significant difference in how quickly and easily distinguishable they are.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is one of the goals for a linked list sort, then a bottom up merge sort using a small (26 to 32) array of pointers to nodes is a much faster method, than using an array oriented top down approach which requires repeated scanning of sub-lists (to emulate random access iterators) in order to split them in half.

Wiki psuedo code:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

I can add example C code if interested.